# How to create a Custom Control Property Grid Property of a list?

Tags: c#, wpf, propertygrid

What I am wanting to do is have a Property for a Custom Control that is editable in the Property Grid in Visual Studio.  I have searched the web for 2 days and I must be approaching it completely wrong since I cannot find anything on this.

[The control I'm building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pF4E.jpg)

I have a UserControl that is a Date and Time selector.  The time list has all the selectable times in a ComboBox (like Outlook).  I want to have a property that is editable in VS that allows me to set the time increments of the times.  i.e.(5, 10, 15, 30 and 60).  If it is set to 30 I get 1:00 AM, 1:30 AM, 2:00 AM...

This is the code that declares the custom control MscDateTimePicker

```
<testUi:MscDateTimePicker Margin="10" DefaultTime="9:00 AM" NearestTime="False" SelectedTime="{Binding SelectedTime}" TimeIncrement="30"/>
```

This is the code for the Custom Control MscDateTimePicker

```
    <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="105" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="78" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <controls:DatePicker Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
           SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedDate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MscDateTimePicker}}}" />
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Times}" DisplayMemberPath="Formatted" IsEditable="True" 
              Text="{Binding DefaultTime}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</Grid>
```

Basicall I just want the Property Grid to have a ComboBox that drops down and shows my increments that would be settable.

```
TimeIncremnt  [        ]
                   5
                  10
                  15
                  30
                  60
```

Comment: What "property grid" are you talking about?

Comment: In Visual Studio, the Properties on the bottom right for a Control.

Comment: I want a property on my custom control MscDateTimePicker that will let me set the TimeIncrement.

Comment: You can declare the property as a dependency property, like the TimeIntervalProperty declared here: https://github.com/SoftFluent/SoftFluent.Windows/blob/master/SoftFluent.Windows/SoftFluent.Windows/DateTimePicker.cs

Comment: The TimeIntevalProperty in the code you reference is just setting a value.  I want to pick the value from a list.